# Rails - Testing Internationalization in Staging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n, staging

I am trying to internationalize a rails application to show German when a user visits the ".de" version of the application and would like to test it in staging before pushing out to production. Is there an easy way to do so without needing a second version (or nth) of the staging server? I don't want to have to have n staging servers up for testing each language of the app.

Answer (score 0):

In your app where you're checking for the `.de` or whatever, you could additionally check for query string parameters. I think `lang` is used quite often. This would allow you to test it without needing to buy more domains or servers.

Here's what I mean:

Request to: https://your-staging-server.com/some-page?lang=de

```
before_action :set_locale

def set_locale
  #domain logic here..
  if params[:lang]
    I18n.locale = params[:lang]
  end
end
```

Optionally save to the session so that the user doesn't need to specify `lang` on every request (and so you don't have to change the application to pass this around):

```
def set_locale
  I18n.locale = params[:lang] || session[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
  session[:locale] = I18n.locale
end
```

I think this is the most common way of doing this. Most people that I know don't have different domains for each language version of their app.